# Failed prop type: Invalid prop 'value'

Tags: react-native

Whenever I try o type into the TextInput I keep getting this warning:
failed prop type invalid prop 'value' of type 'object' supplied to 'textinput' expected 'string'

**LoginForm.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Card, CardSection, Button, Input } from './common';

class LoginForm extends Component {

    state = { email: '', password: '', error: '' };

    render() {
        return (
            <Card>
                <CardSection>
                    <Input 
                    label='Email'
                    placeholder='user@gmail.com'
                    value={this.state.email}
                    onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({ email: email } )}
                    />
                </CardSection>
```

**Input.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { TextInput, View, Text } from 'react-native';

const Input = ({ label, value, onChangeText, placeholder, secureTextEntry }) => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.containerStyle}>
            <Text style={styles.labelStyle}>{ label }</Text>
                <TextInput
                secureTextEntry={secureTextEntry}
                placeholder={placeholder}
                style={styles.inputStyle}
                value={value}
                onChange={onChangeText}
                autoCorrect={false}
                />
        </View>
    );
};
```

Could you please help me to find the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The event listener you need to bind is `onChangeText`

`onChangeText` expects a string param ... where `onChange` expects an object of this form: `nativeEvent: { eventCount, target, text}` ... that's why you're getting this error...

```
<Text style={styles.labelStyle}>{ label }</Text>
                <TextInput
                secureTextEntry={secureTextEntry}
                placeholder={placeholder}
                style={styles.inputStyle}
                value={value}
                onChangeText={onChangeText} // <--Look at this
                autoCorrect={false}
                />
```

Comment: ohh that's so embarrassing !! Thanks a lot !!

Comment: they're quite similar ... and kinda confusing :)

Comment: Yeah I know ...Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

```
onChange={(e) => onChangeText(e.text)}
```

or

```
onChangeText={onChangeText}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It's a typo and I didn't notice it

Answer (score 1):

The error you mentioned or `Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop value of type number supplied to TextInput, expected string` appears when you try to input value of type `number` instead of `string`.

To avoid the error and to follow the best practice for react-native is to wrap the input value with **`String()`** function like this:

```
<TextInput
  value={String(this.props.value)}
  onChange = {this.props.onChange}
  placeholder={"جستجو"}
  blurOnSubmit={false}
  style={{flex:0.9}}
  returnKeyType="done"
/>
```